# How to pass date into function jQuery without calculate the value?

Tags: jquery

I want to pass `v.planned_start_date` exact date as `07-02-2020` to a function, what happen now is the date is minus until getting `-2015`, like this.. `07` minus `02` minus `2020` = `-2015`. How to prevent this happen?

```
var project = '';
$.ajax({
    url : url_api,
    success: function(response){
        $.each(response.data, function(k, v){
            console.log(v.planned_start_date); // the value is 07-02-2020
            project +=  "<div>"+
                            "<input id='chgReqNPSL1"+v.l1_id+"' onchange='chgReqNPSL1(this.id, "+v.planned_start_date+")'>"+
                        "</div>";
            $("#result").append(project);
        });
    }
}); // end of ajax


function chgReqNPSL1(id, planned_start_date){
    console.log(id); // I got the actual ID no issue here
    console.log(planned_start_date); // The problem is here whereby I got -2015 as result not 07-02-2020. Why?
}
```

Comment: Without quotes it looks like a number expression, not a string in the html.

Comment: maybe can answer below on that part only.

Comment: `\""+v.planned_start_date+"\"`

Answer (score 1):

You have two problems here...

1. Without quotes, you're passing a mathematical expression into your function, hence `07 - 02 - 2020 = -2015`
2. You concatenate `project` and append it to `#result` in each iteration of your loop. You probably don't want this as it would result in a lot of duplicate elements

I would suggest instead that you map the `response.data` to an array of jQuery elements, then append that to `#result`. When creating the elements, you can use much safer methods to set data and attributes

```js
success: ({ data }) => {
  $("#result").append(data.map(v => $("<div>").append($("<input>", {
    id: `chgReqNPSL1${v.l1_id}`,
    "data-date": v.planned_start_date // use a data attribute to store the date
  }))))
}
```

You can handle the change events completely separately in a delegated event handler

```js
$("#result").on("change", "input[data-date]", function(e) {
  console.log(this.id)
  console.log(this.dataset.date)
})
```

Demo...

```js
// example response data
const data = [{l1_id:1,planned_start_date:"07-02-2020"},{l1_id:2,planned_start_date:"01-03-2020"}]

const $result = $("#result").on("change", "input[data-date]", function(e) {
  console.log("id:", this.id)
  console.log("date:", this.dataset.date)
  console.log("value:", this.value)
})

// later...
$result.append(data.map(v => $("<div>").append($("<input>", {
  id: `chgReqNPSL1${v.l1_id}`,
  "data-date": v.planned_start_date // use a data attribute to store the date
}))))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```